# Can't define new page mode correctly in Conkeror

Tags: conkeror

I can't seem to get even a basic new page mode working in Conkeror.

In my `.conkerorrc` I have this:

```
define_page_mode("bz_mode", "BZ");
auto_mode_list.push([/bugzilla/, bz_mode]);
```

The documentation suggests (at least to me) that this should be sufficient.  But when I visit (say) `bugzilla.mycompany.com`, I don't see the new mode indicated in Conkeror's mode line.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the trick is to say

```
define_page_mode("bz_mode", $display_name = "BZ");
```

instead.